# form not vertically centered in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two bars:
1.Top bar - Name, Search bar, Account, Cart
2.Navigation Bar (with dropdowns)

The problem is with the top bar. Im trying to have all the elements be on the same line, with Account and Cart on the right side. I tried using flex but now the search bar is not in line with the other elements. Event Account and Cart are kind of off line. When I don't use flex and just try to float Account and Cart to the right, they are swapped(Cart comes first, then Account), and also they don't become in line, they're kind of floating on the top right.

HTML:

```
    <div class="top">
            <h1>TDX</h1>
            <form>
              <div>
                <input type="search" id="mySearch" name="q"
                placeholder="Search the site..." size="50">
                <button>Search</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <a href="account.html"><h4>Account</h4></a>
            <a href="cart.html"><h4>Cart</h4></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="topnav">
          <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Computers</a>
                <a href="#">Tablets</a>
                <a href="#">Cell Phones</a>
                <a href="#">Wearable Technologies</a>
                <a href="#">Accessories</a>
              </div>
          </li>  
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Brands</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Apple</a>
                <a href="#">Samsung</a>
                <a href="#">Lenovo</a>
                <a href="#">Dell</a>
                <a href="#">HP</a>
                <a href="#">Sony</a>
                <a href="#">Panasonic</a>
                <a href="#">Motorola</a>
                <a href="#">HTC</a>
              </div>
          </li> 
          <li><a href="deals.html">Deals</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.topnav li {
    float: left;
}

.topnav li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:120px;
}

.topnav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.top{
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
}

.top a{
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.top h1, .top a{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.top form{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[This is a screenshot of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uljnD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align-items: center;` to your `.top` element in CSS.

Your updated `.top` CSS element:

```
.top {
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7p1phnd8/3/

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it